# Why does this piece of code seem to fail intermittently?

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, enthought, canopy, ansi-escape

I have this piece of inelegant code that's supposed to print out something that looks like this to the console:

[image: goodput]

```
CSI='\x1B['
reset=CSI+'m'

for i in range(len(recs)):
    print CSI+'36;40m' + str(i+1) + '\t\t', recTitles[i], CSI+'33;40m' + recReleaseYears[i] + reset
    print CSI+'35;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'IMDb Rating:\t' + reset, recRatings[i], '('+recVotes[i]+' votes)'
    print CSI+'34;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'Genre:\t\t' + reset, CSI+'36;1m' + recGenres[i] + reset
    print CSI+'33;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'Cast:\t\t' + reset, recCast[i]
    print CSI+'32;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'Director:\t' + reset, recDirectors[i]
    print CSI+'36;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'Summary:\t' + reset, insertTabs(recPlots[i]) + reset
    print CSI+'31;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'IMDb Link:\t' + reset, CSI+'34;1m' + recIMDbLinks[i] + '\n' + reset
```

However, most of the time I get this:
[image: badput]

I'm not sure where the problem lies with my code because occasionally it works as expected and I get the right output (which drives me crazy).

I'm using Enthought Canopy as my IDE.

Comment: Did you upload the same picture twice?

Comment: @Matt No, I did not. If you look closely at the second picture, you'll see that the movie title (Big Hero 6) does not have the black background as it does in the first picture.

Comment: afaik you can print in color using [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html). i think that would make  the code much cleaner and easier to understand/debug.

Answer (score 1):

The problem likely is in the terminal emulator, resetting colors after the tab-characters (which would be a bug).  If you change the tabs so that only spaces are written, it would work around that possibility.

By the way, if your terminal was set to use *hard tabs*, then you could expect some other unexpected behavior (the tabbed area would be *skipped* and not colored).  Here is a screenshot (with the script to demonstrate):
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about that because it always works for the other movie title strings after the first one (i.e. `recTitles[i]` where i > 0), which is a bit perplexing. Here's a screenshot of an expanded output that might help: http://i.imgur.com/VSMoO2O.png

Comment: Presuming that your *data* contains no escape sequences, I don't see any other feature to investigate than the terminal itself.

Answer (score 0):

I still am not sure what the problem might be, but adding a `sys.stdout.flush()` at the beginning of the `for` loop seems to have fixed things.

```
CSI='\x1B['
reset=CSI+'m'
import sys

for i in range(len(recs)):
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print CSI+'36;40m' + str(i+1) + '\t\t', recTitles[i], CSI+'33;40m' + recReleaseYears[i] + reset
    print CSI+'35;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'IMDb Rating:\t' + reset, recRatings[i], '('+recVotes[i]+' votes)'
    print CSI+'34;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'Genre:\t\t' + reset, CSI+'36;1m' + recGenres[i] + reset
    print CSI+'33;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'Cast:\t\t' + reset, recCast[i]
    print CSI+'32;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'Director:\t' + reset, recDirectors[i]
    print CSI+'36;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'Summary:\t' + reset, insertTabs(recPlots[i]) + reset
    print CSI+'31;40m' + u'\u2588' + 'IMDb Link:\t' + reset, CSI+'34;1m' + recIMDbLinks[i] + '\n' + reset
```

Comment: It still looks like a bug in the terminal emulator, since it is supposed to interpret control sequences in the order they are received at the terminal.  Testing with different terminals (without the flush) could be informative.